# Sequelize/NodeJS TINYINT converted into buffer issue

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize in nodejs. My Table structure contains one field data type is **TINYINT**. While I retrieving this field it return **Buffer 01**.

My expected result is either 0 or 1 boolean value.

**Table Structure**

```
myField: {
        type: Sequelize.TINYINT(1)
    }
```

Comment: Before down vote I request to all user If any user do not understand my question please comment here I will explain my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution to check data type **TINYINT** result like following.

```
if(myField && myField[0]=='1'){
    //true
}else{
   //false
}
```